# UINavigationItem Title

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, title, uinavigationitem

Trying to modify title in a UINavigationItem

```
// this modify the title
self.navigationItem.title    = @"Any title";
// this does not
navigationItem.title    = @"Any title";
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigationItem` is not the object it's using. `self.navigationItem` is a readonly property created on demand when using a `UIViewController` with a `UINavigationController`. You can certainly create custom `UINavigationItem` but thats often frowned upon in a standard `UINavigationController` setup, and you shouldn't need to.

As for `self.title`, its merely a shortcut to `self.navigationItem.title`. The reason for the shortcut is it can be used elsewhere in other containment types if necessary including you own custom containers.

If you deconstruct what is happening. it is likely that this is happening, loading your title if you access a navigationItem, which a basic UINavigationController would:

```
- (UINavigationItem)navigationItem
{
    if (!_navigationItem) {
        _navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title];
    }

    return _navigationItem;
}
```

You can read more on what Apple has to say about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationItem